# iOS 7 Maps app not working properly

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

I have updated one of our testing iPad4 with iOS 7.0.4. Earlier it had iOS 6.  Now in my application map view is not loading properly. We use the map to show meeting location by passing coordinates to map view. It worked fine in iOS 6. I haven't done any changes since then. I don't know what is the problem. This is the way I have done my coding.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = latitude;
region.center.longitude = longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.0045;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0045;
[self.mapMeetingLocation setRegion:region];
[self.mapMeetingLocation removeAnnotations:self.mapMeetingLocation.annotations];
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:cordinate];
[self.mapMeetingLocation addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Then to check whether it is a programming issue I run the Apple's Maps app in the same iPad and it has the same issue. I searched London,England it shows screen with so many squares which is similar to the issue that I'm having in my application as well. This happens most of searches I have done with the maps. I have upload an image as well.  [image] . Is this is a bug with Apple? Please help

Comment: Is this iPad connected to the Internet? If it isn't it won't be able to download map tiles

Comment: Yes it is connected to internet for sure.